# Bash script compare number obtained from a cut

Tags: string, bash, shell, scripting

I have a string like this

```
"Hello catch these numbers 20 30"
```

And I have:

```
NUMBER_ONE=$(echo "$line" | cut -d' ' -f5)
NUMBER_TWO=$(echo "$line" | cut -d' ' -f6)
```

When I compare `if [ "$NUMBER_ONE" -gt  "$NUMBER_TWO" ];` I got error, it expect an integer expression. How do I solve?

Comment: Your commands work for me. How *exactly* are you running this? How do you assign to `line`? What's the complete `if` statement?

Comment: Also, try putting `set -x` before these commands, to make the shell print what it thinks is going on as it executes the commands.

Comment: How about `printf "NUMBER_ONE=%s  NUMBER_TWO=%s\n" "$"NUMBER_ONE" "$"NUMBER_TWO"` and see if that doesn't illuminate the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Problem could be in assigning the value "`Hello catch these numbers 20 30`" to the `line` variable. Alternatively, you can use the below approach to achieve the same. It converts the string representation of the number to integer before comparison. In bash, you can perform the converting from anything to integer using `printf -v`. Even floating number will be converted to integer, while anything are not look like a number will be converted to `0`. Exponentiation will be truncated to the number before `e`

```
#!/bin/bash

line="Hello catch these numbers 20 30"

words=$(echo ${line} | sed -e 's/ /\n/g')
nums=($(echo "${words}" | sed -e '/^[0-9]*$/!d'))

printf -v num1 '%d' "${nums[0]}" 2>/dev/null
printf -v num2 '%d' "${nums[1]}" 2>/dev/null

if [[ $num1 -gt $num2 ]]; then
    echo "$num1 is greater than $num2"
elif [[ $num1 -lt $num2 ]]; then
    echo "$num1 is lesser than $num2"
fi
```